# Windows.Data.Text for desktop applications

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-store-apps, desktop-application

I'm looking at the new Windows.Data.Text API with a view to using the WordsSegmenter class. It seems however that it is available only within Windows Store Apps. Anyone know if the API can be used Windows desktop (C# Forms) applications?

Comment: Nope, WordsSegmenter seems to be available also for desktop apps. From its MSDN documentation: "Minimum supported client: Windows 8.1 [Windows Store apps, desktop apps]".

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find any information on the physical dll that I need to reference.

Comment: Note the information "Metadata: Windows.winmd" in the MSDN documentation of WordsSegmenter. Then, you might want to take a look into [Using Windows 8* WinRT API from desktop applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications)